# Mail Merge Gender problem

Tags: macros, branching

I'm trying to construct a form letter, using information stored in a file "data.dat".  It all works, but I am having trouble finding a solution to discriminate between he/she or him/her, depending on the gender of the subject.
I presume it would be a conditional, but how it would look, I have no clue. 
My MWE (at the moment) is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\usepackage[margin=0.75in]{geometry}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\begin{document}

\Fields{\Mr\Dad\DSurName\Ms\Mum\MSurname\Address\StudentFirst\StudentLast}


\Merge{STEMdata.dat}{
\hspace{.25\textwidth}
\begin{flushright}
\bf \Mr\ \Dad\ \DSurName\ \& \Ms\ \Mum\ \MSurname\\
\bf\Address
\end{flushright}
\vspace{2 cm}
\begin{flushright}
\today
\end{flushright}
 \begin{center}
   \textsc{ADVICE OF PROGRESS\\
    COURSE:} 
\end{center}

Dear \Mr\ \DSurName,\par
\StudentFirst\,\StudentLast: \par

This matter has been discussed with \StudentFirst\ and \heshe understands     what is expected in iSTEM in the future.\\
\vfill
\begin{flushright}
\rule{6cm}{0.025cm}\\
Joe Bloggs
\end{flushright}
\newpage
}
\end{document}
```

I have looked at datatool and ifthen, but no luck on where I would replace \heshe in the code.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: do you or any of your packages include https://www.ctan.org/pkg/he-she?

Comment: There's also the `person` package that comes with `datatool`.

Answer (score 1):

You can add an `\ifx` within the merge block. Several other options for conditionals exist, but in this case the built-in seems to work ok. MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{textmerg}
\begin{document}

\def\he{male}
\def\she{female}

\Fields{\SurName\StudentFirst\gender}

\Merge{STEMdatashort.dat}{
\ifx\gender\he
    \def\heshe{he}
\else
    \def\heshe{she}
\fi
Dear Mr. \SurName,\par

The grade of \StudentFirst\ has been discussed and \heshe\ understands what is expected in iSTEM in the future.\\

Joe Bloggs
\newpage
}
\end{document}
```

`STEMdatashort.dat`:

```
Smith
Jenny
female
Brown
Josh
male
```